# Why Vicente Valtieri is a cyrodiilic vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

When you meet Vicente Valtieri and ask him about being a vampire, he explains he was stricken with the disease 300 years ago in the Ashlands of Morrowind.

According with "Inmortal Blood" and my knowledge on vampires in Elder Scrolls series, he should be a Morrowind-type vampire instead of a Cyrodiil-type vampire. So, why is he the second type?

Comment: Maybe a Cyrodillic vampire was visiting Morrowind for a holiday or convention or something

Comment: Why the question was put on hold? This is a question about lore, not about game design

Comment: @Ethan there *is* no lore to explain this. This is just how the developers designed it. We can't tell you what they were thinking.

Comment: During his travels, Vicente found a way to cure his vampirism, but became a vampire once again later in Cyrodiil.

Comment: @Worse_Username that makes no sense, according to game lore once you cure vampirism you can't contract it back, unless you use the console and I don't think Vicente did it, right? LOL

Comment: It is a different kind of vampirism, so that rule doesn't apply to it.

Comment: Ok. I may be misunderstanding. What do u mean by cyrodill vs morrowind vampire?

Comment: @user14172 According to the lore there are different types of vampires on Tamriel. They share some common attributes and powers but differ as well. If you read "Immortal Blood" you'll understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a oversight that is exacerbated by the game's mechanics.

In the Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion there is only one form of vampirism, it is likely too much effort to develop a second form of vampires for this rare exception. This is especially true when considering the vampire mechanics are so poorly tested that the quest to cure vampirism may become bugged [forcing you to permanently remain a vampire](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Vampire_Cure#Bugs). When developing a game of this scale resources cannot always be allocated to give attention to every article of lore the franchise offers.

While the different clans of vampires were distinct in The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind, even imbuing different strengths depending on your clan, there is no mechanic to support the same behavior in TES: Oblivion. As such, this question is never answered in-game and you are free to determine why Vicente does not make further mention of his (assumed) clan lineage.

That being said, he has a [unique weakness to Garlic](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Vicente_Valtieri#Notes). Discreetly placing it in his inventory causes significant debuffs to his character. There is no such item in TES: Morrowind so it's never mentioned in that game. If you so choose, you can attribute this weakness to his Morrowind clan lineage rather than Cyrodiilic brethren - vampires who do not suffer this flaw.